# Inverse of the exponential map in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $(\varphi,U)$ a local coordinate patch (not necessarily exponential coordinates) so that $x,y \in U$. Does the following expression hold in local coordinates when it is well defined after identifying $T_yM$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$?
$$x-y = \exp_y^{-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

No, unless $\varphi = \exp_y$ (up to translation).

You can assume that $y=0$ (i.e. $\varphi(y) = 0$) after translating $\varphi$. Then the question is: does $x = {\exp_y}^{-1}(x)$ hold for every $x$ in $U$? That's just saying that $\varphi = \exp_y$.

Comment: I see, so this is only true in geodesic coordinates. Is it possible to pick geodesic coordinates so that the determinant of the matrix $g_{ij}$ is equal to $1$?

Comment: This is a good question, but a different one. Put differently, you're asking if there are coordinates such that the Riemannian volume form is equal to the standard Euclidean volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (up to sign). The answer is yes and it's a theorem of Moser that you can always find coordinates that work (for any volume form). However these coordinates are most likely not normal coordinates. In fact, you can compute the Taylor expansion of the volume form in normal coordinates, and it shows that if the Riemannian volume form is equal to the Euclidean up to the second order, then (...)

Comment: (...) the Ricci curvature at the point must vanish: see Remark 3.9.7 here: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/uploads/vincent.minerbe/Geodiff/m2dg.pdf. Conversely, if your manifold is Ricci flat, then does the Riemannian volume form equate to the Euclidean volume form in normal coordinates? I don't know, but I doubt it. You could certainly ask the question though.